# Constant high CPU usage because of sound card interrupt

Tags: cpu-load, interrupts

One of my 16 CPU cores is always working at around 50% CPU capacity. There is nothing showing in `htop` or `top` which indicates a high usage, so I started digging and found with (`cat /proc/interrupts`) that the cause of the high usage (and high temperature of that core) is due to a frquent interrupt generated by the sound card.

IR-IO-APIC   16-fasteoi   i801_smbus, snd_hda_intel:card0

Any ideas how to solve it? Surely a CPU core constantly under 50% load is not healthy.

If I disable USB Audio from BIOS there are no more interrupts, but then I get no sound.

Greatly appreciated.